# Protect against limited distributed denial of service with help from memcached, or is there a better alternative?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, memcached, ddos

I'm adding to a Wordpress blog a simple HTML input to allow users to provide their emails. I don't want to buy a third-party service or use a cloud-based endpoint like AWS API Gateway that triggers a lambda function to interface with a backend database for persistence.

I simply want to use my own database -- the one I'm using with Wordpress, to store user provided emails.

My concern is, once I go this route, I open the blog up to denial of service attacks. In order to mitigate this risk, I'd like to implement a key/value service (like memcached or redis) to limit attacks from would-be script kiddies using the same IP address.

Is the use of memcached or redis the right approach for this problem? I want to store the IP address and query against it before I allow another submittal. If the IP address exists in the key/value store, I'd throw up a recaptcha, resetting the database every x hours.

Is there a key/value service that's even smaller than these solutions, or am I overthinking this? I just want to limit the effect a service like this has on my server as much as is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Is the wordpress site already hosted on AWS like in EC2 instances or something?

Is it behind a load balancer that AWS manages?

If so, [AWS Shield](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/) is already in place to help mitigate DdoS and its free. Shield Advanced is another offering but that would be overkill for you and way too expensive ($3,000/mo) - Shield Advanced is basically insurance (so you don't pay for your resources that spun up to meet the attack, and you also have access to a 24x7 team at AWS when a DdoS attack is detected.

You also may want to look into setting up a web application firewall (WAF) - not necessarily for DdoS but for other attack vectors.

A caching layer would "help" in keeping your website up and running in the event of a DdoS attack. Obviously you want your site to maintain availability during an attack for real users so creating some auto-scaling and caching would aid in that regard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, much appreciated. But I was asking about DDOS as it pertains to user input and databases. I use Cloudflare for protection and VPSes w/stateful firewalls via AWS. My question more pertained to the footprint of a service and the effects it could have on performance.

Comment: Gotcha. Well AWs Shield and the AWS network would prevent a user from hitting your endpoint with the same IP over and over again.   However, for something like this maybe Redis or perhaps you could store the users IP in session, and use something like DynamoDB as your session store.